# How to initialize readonly item collection with resource in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Suppose I have some control with readonly `Items` collection. I can initialize this collection using a collection syntax:

```
<Something>
    <Something.Items>
        <Item />
        <Item />
    </Something.Items>
</Something>
```

Suppose now I have collection in resources and want initialize my control with it:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ItemCollectionClass x:Key="collection">
        <Item />
        <Item />
    </ItemCollectionClass>
</Window.Resources>
```

How to do it? `<Something Items="{StaticResource collection}" />` doesn't work since it's trying to set the collection instance, not initialize it.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, in most cases you would just use an `ItemsSource` property for this.

Comment: Made inherited class with new `ItemsSource` dependency property. App works but for some reason designer shows empty collection.

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is. When you declare something as resource, it was like a static object. It's initialized at the time the resource dictionary is loaded. So, what's the point?

Comment: The difference is that in first case runtime calls `Something.Items.Add()` for each item. In second case it's `Something.Items = FindResource("collection")` which throws exception because `Items` property is readonly.

Comment: @Porna, so can you tell me why cant you make it writeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize the collection with an ObjectDataProvider:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ItemCollectionClass x:Key="collection">
    <Item />
    <Item />
  </ItemCollectionClass>

  <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="..." ObjectType="{x:Type local:Something}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="collection" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
  </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources />
```